# Does Bing support anything like Google's First Click Free program?

Tags: seo, google, bing, advertising, vs

Google has a program for webmasters called [First Click Free](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=74536).

> To implement First Click Free, you need to allow all users who find a document on your site via Google search to see the full text of that document, even if they have not registered or subscribed to see that content. The user's first click to your content area is free. However, once that user clicks a link on the original page, you can require them to sign in or register to read further. The user must be able to see the full content of a multi-page article. You can allow this by displaying all content on a single page to both Googlebot and users. Alternatively, you can use cookies to make sure that a user can visit each page of a multi-page article before being asked for registration or payment.

Does Bing support anything like this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Bing does not have a first click free policy on their terms and conditions, you could always contact there [advertising support team and ask](http://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/contact-sales-and-support) if you want to double, triple check.

Answer (score 1):

Bing doesn't publish any documentation saying they support "first click free" (FCF).  However, sites that use FCF algorithms rank in Bing just as well as in Google.

For example, the New York Times content is normally protected by paywall, but you can access it through either Google or Bing search.  While Bing doesn't appear to officially endorse the way this works (like Google does), NYT content remains accessible through Bing.

If you implemented FCF for Bing the same way that you implement it for Google, the risk would be that you eventually get booted from the Bing search engine.  I'd judge that to be relatively low risk since they don't usually provide much traffic anyway, they are unlikely to notice what you are doing, they are unlikely to care if they do notice, and you can  request re-inclusion with them afterwards if you adjust your algorithms.